# Android marshmallow : Galaxy Note 4 Screen Overlay Detected

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have a Samsung note 4 phone. I am facing error of Screen Overlay Detected message.
[image: Screen Overlay Detected]

Please tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: Is this an app you're developing yourself or an app on your phone that you use?

Comment: I am developing that app.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with my Samsung Note 4. In my case it was the Side key panel which was causing this problem. I turned it off and the problem went away.

*Settings -> Display and Wallpaper -> One-handed operation. Uncheck Side key panel.*

If this doesn't apply to you or doesn't solve the issue, please check other apps that have 'Draw over other apps' or 'Apps that can appear on top' setting enabled. Try disabling the setting for each app and see if it resolves the issue. The usual suspects are Clean Master, Twilight, File Manager, any battery saving app among others.

Comment: ``Settings -> Display and Wallpaper -> One-handed operation.``  all option in that are unchecked and Draw over app setting also unchecked . and even I disable the setting for each app.

Answer (score 0):

De-install from clean master was the solution for a Acer liquid 4G to get rid of the above problem... After the problem was gone I did not try to install clean master again...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this alert after a "dangerous permission" system alert.

As long as Android 6.x is buggy on some devices where this "overlay alert" is displayed without any reason (on 2 to 5% of the devices according to my analytics data), the best solution is to avoid the whole permission process by defining the targetSdk to 22.

Take care that you can't downgrade the target sdk for a new version or this will induce a INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_DOWNGRADE error when the user updates requiring an unisntall/install of the app.